# What is "__maybe_unused"?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

While looking at the Linux kernel, I noticed the line:

```
static void *malloc(size_t size) __maybe_unused;
```

in Linux v3.2 /arch/frv/kernel/gdb_stub.c .  I've never seen `__maybe_unused` used before.  Is it specific to the Linux kernel? Or is it defined in the C spec?  And what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In `include/linux/compiler-gcc.h` there is the definition of the `__maybe_unused` macro:

```
#define __maybe_unused  __attribute__((unused))
```

and in `gcc` manual you have the documentation of the `unused` attribute for functions:

> unused "This attribute, attached to a function, means that the function is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this function."

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

and for variables:

> unused "This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this variable."

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Answer (score 11):

From the [commit that introduced the attribute:](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0d7ebbbc6eaa5539f78ab20ed6ff1725a4e332ef)

> __maybe_unused is defined to be __attribute__((unused)) for both function
>   and variable use if it could possibly be unreferenced due to the
>   evaluation of preprocessor macros. Function prototypes shall be marked
>   with __maybe_unused if the actual definition of the function is dependant
>   on preprocessor macros.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the commit.